# What is the best way to stream video from a smartphone with the least delay possible?

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, video-capture, video-processing

We want to control a RC vehicle located in America from another continent. So we want to transmit real time video (from a smartphone, **with the least delay possible**). For the first version, we used google hangouts, but looking for a better option.

Should I develop my own smartphone app, and show the video in a web browser? Or is there a commercial option that solves this problem? What would you do in my position?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think that WebRTC is the way to go.

Check this out:
http://peerjs.com/

Also - Wowza is pretty user-friendly and is offering it as a preview.
https://www.wowza.com/products/capabilities/webrtc-streaming-software

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a live encoder app on your smartphone, capable of publishing live RTMP streams, preferably with H.264/AAC encoding.
Broadcast-Me is worth to try:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.something.hppc.sp13bcs

The app will publish live stream to some streaming server like Wowza Streaming Engine or Unreal Media Server; then you can view this stream in many different ways - web-based or with standalone players like VLC.